# Cant gain permission to edit registry values with winreg

Tags: python, registry, uac, winreg

after running the following line:

```
Key = OpenKey(Reg, REG_PATH,0,KEY_WRITE)
```

i get `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

im tring to write some system registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

i tried to run the python script from cmd that was opened as admin but it still gave me the same results.

How can i ask for permissions using UAC or in any other way?

My goal overall is to change the default render/playback device in windows multimedia, im trying to do so by changing reg values so far.

Comment: can you perform the same write from `reg` command (elevated) or regedit? maybe there's an issue in the key path.

Comment: the key path is good because i was able to read it before writing to it, i can change those values from regedit